# PHP - Storing account ID from MYSQL database in PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error);

$_SESSION['id'] = $id ;

echo ("ID: ".$_SESSION["id"]."");
```

It outputs "ID: 0" while the id of the account in the database should be 1 instead. Please help!

Comment: have a look at what `var_dump($id)` outputs after your myswl_query and that should give you a hint as to where it's going wrong.

Comment: $id will return a resource value like #7 resource. Its not a good thing to save it in your session!

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` returns a resource. The returned result resource should be passed to `mysql_fetch_array()`, and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'] ;
}
echo ("ID: ".$_SESSION["id"]."");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! It works! Alright. Gonna read up on preventing mysql injections.

Comment: Hi @JW, all is working well but is it possible to store the same id in the session to the database? I tried to store the same id from the session to the database but it won't be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error);

while($myid = mysql_fetch_array($id)){

$_SESSION['id'] = $myid ;

}

echo ("ID: ".$_SESSION["id"]."");
```